# Lambda sort using Reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection, abstract-class

I'm working on a project that requires the use of sorted Class lists, and I have a lambda expression that worked according to the type of class I needed to be sorted. The sorting occurs on a date field of the class itself:

```
Comparator<Class1> comparatorDescending = (exp1, exp2) -> exp2.getDate().compareTo(exp1.getDate());
        this.classlist2sort.sort(comparatorDescending);
```

However I have two, maybe more classes that need to be sorted in this way and I decided to move the lambda expression above to the parent class and make it a generic. This required a bit of work however in that I now need to pass into the parent class the type of class I'm dealing with (Class1.class), condition on that, then sort with generic. I tried the following using Reflection:

```
Method m = this.typeParameterClass.getDeclaredMethod("getDate");

Comparator<T> comparatorDescending = (exp1, exp2) ->
                m.invoke(exp2).compareTo(m.invoke(exp1));
this.classlist2sort((Comparator<? super T>) comparatorDescending);
```

Doing so gave me an error message: `Unhandled exceptions: java.lang.IllegalAccessException, java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` to which I followed the suggested workaround of surrounding the expression with a try catch in the following manner:

```
Method[] input = this.typeParameterClass.getDeclaredMethods();
Method m = this.typeParameterClass.getDeclaredMethod("getDate");

Comparator<T> comparatorDescending = (exp1, exp2) -> {
            try {
                return m.invoke(exp2).compareTo(m.invoke(exp1));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
this.classlist2sort((Comparator<? super T>) comparatorDescending);
```

Unfortunately, doin this resulted in a `Cannot resolve method 'compareTo' in 'Object'` error. I am wondering now if what I'm trying to do is possible. Any help is appreciated

Comment: How do you address the fact that o is unknown at runtime, which lead me to incorporate Reflection in the first place?

Comment: I've posted an answer that addresses using reflection for this. Hope that helps.

Comment: it might help if you included some examples of the classes that you are trying to sort

Comment: You can simplify the first approach to `Comparator<Class1> comparatorDescending = Comparator.comparing(Class1::getDate).reversed();` And now think about it: even if you repeat this line a dozen times for a dozen different classes, it’s simpler than what you are trying to do with Reflection. Not to speak of more readable, more robust, type safe, and more efficient.

Comment: @Holger You are not wrong. Actually, the only reason I considered Reflection was not because it would be cool to do, it was so that I could avoid sharing state between my subclass and superclass. Using reflection enabled me to do the sorting in the parent class and write getter/setter methods in the subclass to access state where and when needed. Using the prior, simpler approach would have forced me to share access to state and didn't fit in the spirit of how my subclasses and superclass relate to one another.

Comment: The usual approach would be to make the method generic, i.e. add a type parameter `<T extends Class1>` and add a parameter like a `Function<T,…>` to access a property or a `Comparator<T>` to determine the required order. Unless you’re assuming that every subclass has a `getDate` method (which would be weird, as you could simply declare an abstract method then), the name of the method would have to be a parameter anyway, so using a `Function` instead is still decoupling superclass and subclass, but in a typesafe way.

Comment: @Holger Not quite. I think what I will do is edit the original post and show the basic structure to illustrate more clearly what the problem was. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast the return value of the method to `Comparable` (you will have to make sure the return value of `getDate` matches this). The comparator can also be simplified using `Comparator.comparing`.

```java
try {
    Method m = this.typeParameterClass.getDeclaredMethod("getDate");
    this.classlist2sort.sort(Comparator.comparing(o -> {
        try {
            return (Comparable) m.invoke(o);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }).reversed());
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e); // or other handling
}
```

Comment: That worked for me. I had to add `.reversed()` to the Comparator to get it to sort in the order that I needed, and I changed the `(Comparable)` cast to have it be what I needed as well, In this case `(LocalDate)`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the source code of `Class1`, `Class2`, etc. you can define an interface to be used for the comparator and avoid reflection altogether. Let's say:

```
public interface HasDate {

  LocalDate getDate();
}
```

I know the name is bad, but it will do for an example. Define the comparator to work with `HasDate`, and you can sort lists, whose elements implement the interface.

```
public class RandomStuff {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Comparator<HasDate> dateComparator = (o1, o2) -> o2.getDate().compareTo(o1.getDate());

    List<Class1> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add(new Class1(LocalDate.now()));
    list1.add(new Class1(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1)));
    list1.add(new Class1(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1)));
    list1.sort(dateComparator);
    System.out.println(list1);

    List<Class2> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    list2.add(new Class2(LocalDate.now()));
    list2.add(new Class2(LocalDate.now().plusDays(1)));
    list2.add(new Class2(LocalDate.now().minusDays(1)));
    list2.sort(dateComparator);
    System.out.println(list2);
  }
}
```